# Opening a GitHub Repository in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, github

I'm trying to explore a GitHub repository using VS2015. I Fork the repo into my GitHub account. Then I use the Team Explorer window to clone it to my computer. Now how do I open & run it? There are no solution files to open. I've read you can open it as a website, but then I can't get TypeScript to compile the .ts files. I've tried the `File -> New -> Project From Existing Code` option, but there's no option there for an ASP.NET website - it's just Console App, Class Library and Windows App.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you may want to use Visual Studio 2017 RC, which has native "open folder" support or use VSCode.